# Resolving ascii codec can't decode byte in position ordinal not in range

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, decoding

I've seen all of the other posts and done quite a bit of research but I am still scratching my head.

Here is the problem:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=u'My Mate\u2019s'
>>> b='\xe2\x80\x99s BBQ'
>>> print a
My Mate’s
>>> print b
’s BBQ
```

So, the variables are finely printed themselves, but printing a concatenation:

```
>>> print a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

gives a decode error. So, I try to decode the string:

```
>>> print a.decode('utf-8')+b.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error changes into an encode error. So, I try a couple of ways to inform the encoding:

```
>>> print a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')+b.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print a.decode('ascii','ignore')+b.decode('ascii','ignore')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print a.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii','ignore') +b.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii','ignore')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

The error persists no matter what I try.

I suppose the problem might be very simple. I'd appreciate someone helping with an explanation of what's going on, and how to resolve this.

I have python 2.7 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b` is encoded as UTF-8 so you have to `.decode` it to Unicode.

```
print a + b.decode('utf-8')
```

Tested in Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu.

If you want both in UTF-8 you can do:

```
print a.encode('utf-8') + b
```

---

I'll explain why each one of your attempts doesn't work:

```
a + b # the default decoding is ascii which cannot decode UTF-8
a.decode('utf-8')+b.decode('utf-8') # you don't need to decode Unicode
```

Again you don't need to decode Unicode.

```
a.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')+b.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
```

You keep trying to decode Unicode. What you should do instead is to encode it, or to decode `b`.

```
a.decode('ascii','ignore')+b.decode('ascii','ignore')
```

And finally you again try to decode Unicode. The point to be made here is that UTF-8 is an encoding. You decode from UTF-8 to Unicode.

```
a.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii','ignore') +b.decode('utf-8').encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: ah. light bulbs lighting up. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you.